# QTcpSocket: decoding received data

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcpsocket

I need to decode the data received from Universal Robot UR5 server. The data received is below. Can somebody please help me with decoding this message using Qt5 c++?

```
\x00\x00\x04T@\xE2\xB2\xB8\xD4\xFD\xF3\xB6@\t\"\xD0\xE5`A\x8A\xBF\xF9\"\xD0\xE5`A\x88?\xF9\"\xD0\xE5`A\x89@\x12\xD9\x16\x87+\x02\f@\x12\xD9\x16\x87+\x02\f@\t\"\xD0\xE5`A\x89\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xBB\xE0""f\xD1\x1B\xE1\x95\x8B\xBF\xF5\xB6\x18\xBE\xB0YA\xBF\xF5\xB8\x9E\xE6\xCB\xD9\xBC\xBF\xC4^\\\xFC^\x81i\xBE\xEE@\x01\xF2\xD7\b\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xBC\x19\xE2""B\x00\x00\x00\x00\xC0""1!\xAF\x86w&m\xC0""1#\xAD""b\x1C\xD9\xCE\xBF\xF7\xB5\xA6.\xF4Tz\xBF!\x9B\x1B\xF6\x80\xFFP\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\t\"\xD0\xE0\x00\x00\x00\xBF\xF9\"\xD0\xD1\x10\xB4`?\xF9\"\xD0\xE0\x00\x00\x00@\x12\xD9\x16\x80\x00\x00\x00@\x12\xD9\x16\x80\x00\x00\x00@\t\"\xD0\xE0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xBB\xE0""f\xD1 \x00\x00\x00\xBF\xF5\xB6\x18\xC0\x00\x00\x00\xBF\xF5\xB8\x9E\xE0\x00\x00\x00\xBF\xC4^]\x00\x00\x00\x00\xBE\xEE@\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xBB\xE0""f\xD1 \x00\x00\x00\xBF\xF5\xB6\x18\xC0\x00\x00\x00\xBF\xF5\xB8\x9E\xE0\x00\x00\x00\xBF\xC4^]\x00\x00\x00\x00\xBE\xEE@\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?\xDF(\xD4\xDE\xE9Z\x10?\xBB\xF7\xD1N%*9?\xD0\xC2\xE6\xB9\x87\x1C\xE1@\x01\xC4\xB7+\x83\x8B\xD2@\x01\xC4\xB7\x14\xE4\x1D\xCA>\x93q]e!\xED\xD8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00>\xAE\x18\xA0\x85\x9A\xCB'>\x8B\r\xC1""E\x1F\x9C\x06>\xAC\xB0\xAA\xDB\xDFm,\xBEkF\xDE""b\x8D\xBCQ>\x95\xADv\x92\xF8(\xF5\xBD\xE3\xFC\x04\x11\xC6\xD3\x19?\xDF(\xD4\xA9\xCF\xAD\x8C?\xBB\xF7\xD2\x15\x90\xF0\xA6?\xD0\xC2\xE6\xCB\xBC]O@\x01\xC4\xB7""6\x1C\xF6\x04@\x01\xC4\xB7\x1F\x7F\xE0M>\x97\x96""3\x90\xB0*\xE2\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@D\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@D\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@D\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@D\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@D\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@D\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?\xC1\xF0g\x05\xC8\x96\xDD@ \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x1C\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@o\xA0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@o\xA0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@o\xA0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@o\xA0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@o\xA0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@o\xA0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?\xF0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x13\xB8\xAA\x9D\x1AX\xAE@\x14k\xD0*\xDC-\xAE@\x15\xAEW\xC1q\x0E\xBC@\f\xDBv7\x18'\xDA@\x0B\x03t\x19\x01\xE5{?\xF1\x05\x92*d
```

This works with the python code below. But I need to do this in Qt5 c++.

```
     s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
     s.settimeout(10)
     s.connect((HOST, PORT_30003))
     time.sleep(1.00)
     print ""
     packet_1 = s.recv(4)
     packet_2 = s.recv(8)
     packet_3 = s.recv(48)
     packet_4 = s.recv(48)
     packet_5 = s.recv(48)
     packet_6 = s.recv(48)
     packet_7 = s.recv(48)

     #reading current joint values from 48 bytes

     packet_18 = s.recv(8)
     packet_18 = packet_18.encode("hex") #convert the data from \x hex notation to plain hex
     q1 = str(packet_18)
     q1 = struct.unpack('!d', packet_18.decode('hex'))[0]
     print "q1 = ", q1 * 180/3.1416

     packet_19 = s.recv(8)
     packet_19 = packet_19.encode("hex") #convert the data from \x hex notation to plain hex
     q2 = str(packet_19)
     q2 = struct.unpack('!d', packet_19.decode('hex'))[0]
     print "q2 = ", q2 * 180/3.1416

     packet_20 = s.recv(8)
     packet_20 = packet_20.encode("hex") #convert the data from \x hex notation to plain hex
     q3 = str(packet_20)
     q3 = struct.unpack('!d', packet_20.decode('hex'))[0]
     print "q3 = ", q3 * 180/3.1416

     packet_21 = s.recv(8)
     packet_21 = packet_21.encode("hex") #convert the data from \x hex notation to plain hex
     q4 = str(packet_21)
     q4 = struct.unpack('!d', packet_21.decode('hex'))[0]
     print "q4 = ", q4 * 180/3.1416

     packet_22 = s.recv(8)
     packet_22 = packet_22.encode("hex") #convert the data from \x hex notation to plain hex
     q5 = str(packet_22)
     q5 = struct.unpack('!d', packet_22.decode('hex'))[0]
     print "q5 = ", q5 * 180/3.1416

     packet_23 = s.recv(8)
     packet_23 = packet_23.encode("hex") #convert the data from \x hex notation to plain hex
     q6 = str(packet_23)
     q6 = struct.unpack('!d', packet_23.decode('hex'))[0]
     print "q6 = ", q6 * 180/3.1416
```

Comment: Is there any way to replicate the server?

Comment: The server is a robot simulator software from Universal Robot. I don't know any way to replicate it.  But the simulator can be downloaded from the links below: [link](https://www.universal-robots.com/download/?option=51823#section16597)

Comment: @eyllanesc link for linux is: [link](https://www.universal-robots.com/download/?option=51821#section16632)

Comment: Assuming that I download the SW and execute it, what else do I have to do to be able to use your script?

Comment: If you have a windows machine the simulator should be run on VMware player, beacuse it is linux based. And you just need to connect to the corresponding IP of the virtual machine and port 30003. There will be 3 robot simulator software on the main screen UR3, UR5 and UR10, you just need to run one of them and then you can run the script.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to decode the data myself with the code below:

```
// joint values
double q1 = 0, q2=0, q3=0, q4=0, q5=0, q6=0;
// pose values
double x = 0, y=0, z=0, rX=0, rY=0, rZ=0;

QByteArray array;
array = p_socket->readAll();

// decoding length data
int length = 0;
memcpy(&length, array.constData(), 4);
length = qToBigEndian(length);
qDebug() << length;

int byteLength = 8;

// decoding joint 1 value
QByteArray jointArray1 = array.mid(252,byteLength).toHex();
long long currentJointPosition1=jointArray1.toLongLong(0,16);
q1 = reinterpret_cast<double&>(currentJointPosition1);

// decoding joint 2 value
QByteArray jointArray2 = array.mid(252+1*byteLength,byteLength).toHex();
long long currentJointPosition2=jointArray2.toLongLong(0,16);
q2 = reinterpret_cast<double&>(currentJointPosition2);
```